# Angular 2, ResolveGuard,Angular http,

Tags: http, angular, observable, resolve

My service for http get call

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { IAppInfo } from './appInfo';
import { IProduct } from './product';
@Injectable()
export class AppInfoService {
  private _appInfoUrl : string = "api/appInfo/appInfo.json";
 //constructor
 constructor (private _http : Http){}

 getAppInfo() : Observable<IAppInfo[]>  {
    return this._http.get(this._appInfoUrl)
                .map((response : Response) => <IAppInfo[]>response.json())
                .do(data => console.log('Service'+JSON.stringify(data)))
                .catch(this.handleError);
    }
    private handleError(error : Response){
      console.error(error);
      return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'servererror');
    }
}
```

its my service I am using this service in my Guard

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve } from '@angular/router';
import { IAppInfo } from './appInfo';
import { AppInfoService } from './appInfo.service';
@Injectable()
export class AppInfoResolveGuard implements Resolve<IAppInfo[]> {
    appInfo : IAppInfo[];
    errormessage : string;
    constructor (private _appInfoService : AppInfoService ){
        console.log("Resolve Guard");
    }
    resolve()  {
        console.log('guard'+this._appInfoService.getAppInfo());
        return this._appInfoService.getAppInfo();                  
    }
}
```

and pass this resolve to router path

```
 { path: 'rklob', resolve: {app : AppInfoResolveGuard }, component:   RklobAppComponent },
```

and fetch that data in my component class

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Route } from '@angular/router';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { IAppInfo } from './appInfo';
import { AppInfoService } from './appInfo.service';
import { IWelcome } from './home/welcome';
@Component({
    selector: 'rklob-app-main',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'rklob-app.component.html'
})
export class RklobAppComponent implements OnInit {
    appInfo : IAppInfo[];
    appWelcome : IWelcome;
    appAbout : IAbout;
    appService : IServices[];
    appPerson : IPerson[];
    appClientGallery : IClientGallary[];
    appPackage : IPackage[];
    appAddresses : IAddress[];
    errormessage : string;

    constructor (private _route : ActivatedRoute, private _appInfoService :        AppInfoService){
        console.log('component');
    }
    ngOnInit(){
      this.appInfo = this._route.snapshot.data['app'];
      for(let data of this.appInfo){
          console.log(data.captionData);
          this.appWelcome.captionData = data.captionData;
          this.appWelcome.welcomeInfo = data.welcomeInfo;
      }
    }
}
```

`console.log(data.captionData);` show display a value but its can assign to
`this.appWelcome.captionData` and `this.appWelcome.welcomeInfo = data.welcomeInfo;`
its give me a error like

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property
>   'captionData' of undefined TypeError: Cannot set property
>   'captionData' of undefined

how can I assign a `this.appWelcome.captionData = data.captionData;`

Comment: The error refers  to your `appWelcome` object which is not initialized.
It is not refering to returned data.

Comment: I dont see any issue..

Comment: if I am set like this   ** appWelcome : IWelcome = { captionData : "" , welcomeInfo : ""};** its work to me but its a proper way or not? plz tell me. If **appWelcome is a array of object**  then can I do like this =>  **appWelcome : IWelcome[] = [{ captionData : "" , welcomeInfo : ""}];** ? is it true

Comment: thanx to solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`appWelcome` is not initialized. You can assign an empty object to it and that would solve the issue (note that you might need to add attributes with null values to satisfy the IWelcome interface at compile time):

```
appWelcome : IWelcome = {};
```